# Makefile which link to library in C++

Tags: c++, makefile, libcurl, ubuntu-12.04

Recently, I try to create an makefile as below:

```
all:
     g++ test.cpp -o Test
```

It creates an runnable `Test`. However, If I try to link it to an library (as `LibCurl` to use SSL connetion):

```
all:
     g++ test.cpp -o Test -lcurl
```

It goes wrong (I already installed `libcurl4-openssl-dev` package as standard library)!
What does I miss? Can you give any solution? Thanks!!

Edit: The error is below:

```
fatal error: curl.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what "it goes wrong" means?

Comment: 1) Does the same thing happen when you try `g++` on the command line, without Make? This is a linking problem, not a makefile problem. 2) *Where* did you install libcurl?

Comment: 1) `fatal error: curl.h: No such file or directory` this is not a linker problem, compiler cannot find the path the header file 2) Do you mean `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` ?

Comment: yes! I mean `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`!

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is the problem, but for all packages that you install via package manager, you can get all the linking and compile flags via `pkg-config --cflags --libs libfoo`

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you need fix your sources:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

The header files are missing in the include search path.

You will have install the development package of libcurl. 
For example, install libcurl-devel-7.19.0-11.1.x86_64.rpm  for Open Suse 11.1.

To know the list of files that would be installed by the rpm, download the rpm, type the following command in the downloaded dir.

`rpm -qlp <rpmname>`

As per the example above, the command would be 
`rpm -qlp libcurl-devel-7.19.0-11.1.x86_64.rpm`

This will list the files along with the path in which it would be installed to.
In our example, the result would look like..

`/usr/include/curl`                                                                      `/usr/include/curl/curl.h`                                                            `/usr/include/curl/curlbuild.h`
`/usr/include/curl/curlrules.h`
`/usr/include/curl/curlver.h`  and so on...

and

Install the development libcurl package for the version of linux you use and include `#include <curl/curl.h>` in your code.

Refer http://curl.haxx.se/download.html to download the right one